Can I daisy-chain two Steam Deck hubs for dual screen with Steam Deck?
My PC died, and so did one of my two monitors, and so, temporarily I'm forced to utilize my Steam Deck as my main PC. It works perfectly fine in that role, with use of an "8 in 1" USB hub, which passes power from the PSU, allows using HDMI, keyboard, mouse, and Ethernet. But I'm very used to having two monitors, and I'm considering buying a second one first before I go about getting a new PC (the old one was so old the Steam Deck is actually a decent upgrade).
I have a second such hub, and I can plug it into the "Type-c3.1" port of the first one. I could plug a new monitor into its HDMI. The big question is: will it work? If it won't, there's no sense buying the second monitor yet. Or maybe you know of some other means of connecting 2 HDMI monitors (and a bunch of USB ports and power) to Steam Deck?
The kind of hub I'm using:


A Steam Deck can support up to two external displays in desktop mode. I'm not sure that hub supports daisy-chaining displays though (The usb-c port should be labeled for displayport/+DP). Can you connect the steam deck > hub1 > hub2 > monitor1 ? If so, there's a good chance you can run 2 monitors

@Cpt.Whale Thanks. Did as you suggested, didn't work, seems the answer is "No."
